# Referring an array inside a C structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I come from Java background and trying to understand C structures, pointers and arrays better. Here's the sample code that I am playing with:

If the following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "Hello";
    printf("%c",string[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the following return with an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    typedef struct{
        int x;
        char string[8];
    }ST_DATA;

    ST_DATA *my_data;
    my_data->x = 100;
    my_data->string = "Hello"; // issues a warning, described below

    printf("%d",my_data->x); // works fine
    printf("%c",my_data->string[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the error that I am getting:

Compilation error            time: 0 memory: 2292 signal:0

prog.c: In function ‘main’:

prog.c:12:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[8]’ from type ‘char *’

my_data->string = "Hello";

I tried with the following changes as well:

**a)**

```
my_data->string[] = "Hello";
```

This will give me the following error:

prog.c: In function ‘main’:

prog.c:12:18: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token

my_data->string[] = "Hello";

```
              ^
```

**b)**

```
my_data->string[8] = "Hello";
```

This returns with a runtime error. Presumably, the error occurs when I am printing the first character.

There must be something stupid that I am doing or expecting (being used to coding with other languages than C), but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening and how to get it to work. I'd greatly appreciate any *pointers* (ha! get it?)

Comment: it should be strcpy(my_data->string,"Hello";)

Comment: Understood. Thanks! Although, why does it work in the first code snippet then. I am essentially trying to do the same thing, only this time, the array is inside the structure. That is what is confusing me

Comment: @swap_1712 Check my answer below to clear your confusion. Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case, you are automatically allotting memory for `char string[] = "Hello"`. The compiler takes care of memory management here.

In the second, `my_data` is a pointer and you need to allot memory to it manually, before you assign something to it.

You can:

```
ST_DATA *my_data = (ST_DATA *)malloc(sizeof(ST_DATA));
```

It'd be good you spend some time reading about automatic memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

[strcpy()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flinux.die.net%2Fman%2F3%2Fstrcpy&ei=ZIQgU9vROOfI4AT45oAI&usg=AFQjCNGe1-2xgvRTx1buu3WsTh_TtOqmrg&sig2=oPvHwgBaH_tDF7FzZ_IfoQ&bvm=bv.62788935,d.bGE) need to be used to copy strings into string members of structure `ST_DATA`.

`strcpy(my_data->string, "Hello");`

Before you have to allocate memory for your structure as,

`ST_DATA *my_data = (ST_DATA *) malloc(sizeof(ST_DATA));`

EDIT: The structure `ST_DATA` inside main() is just a declaration which tells compiler that it has members of what type they are. How can you use it until it is allocated memory. You can think `ST_DATA` as a data type similar to any other data types as `int` etc which has no meaning when they are not defined as `int object` which gets memory for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ST_DATA *my_data;
my_data->x = 100;
```

here my_data is a pointer so first allocate memory to it.

```
char string[] = "Hello";
```

here string is assigned value with declaration so it if fine. but in next code

```
my_data->string = "Hello";
```

is not ok since initialization can be done only with declaration. after declaration for string value has to be assigned using `strcpy()`

Comment: Thanks! Although, that part of the code seems to be working. I've been able to print the value of integer just fine. Just not the string. I added some more explanation as to what I have tried. Thanks again.